# TypeScript map with keys having multiple types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How to declare a map in typescript where the key could be a string | number and the value could be for example a number.

I'm trying the following and get an error

```
let aMap : { [key: string | number]: number } = {}
```

I get the following error in VS Code

> [ts] An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.

Note: I do not want to use the keyword "Map" in typescript. As just declaring:

`let aMap : { [key: string]: number } = {}`
works fine, I'm just having issues creating map with multiple key types

Comment: That's an object literal not a es6 Map?

Answer (score 3):

Ahh, I figured out what was causing it finally. It's weird that I was not able to find this on the web. You can use the following syntax:

```
const testmap: {
  [key: number]: number;
  [key: string]: number;
} = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

From Typescript,

> JavaScript object keys are always coerced to a string, so obj[0] is always the same as obj["0"].

Maybe the error is because number can also work with string.

I've found a situation that two custom types properties can be joined and result object contains anyone of the property. For that we can use Union or Intersection Types feature.

```
interface Colorful {
  color: string;
}
interface Circle {
  radius: number;
}
 
type ColorfulCircle = Colorful | Circle;
```

In the above code, ColorfulCircle can have both the properties of Colourful and Circle
Source: [TS - keyof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html), [TS - Intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), [StackOverflow - Union vs Intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61371001/4067157)