# What means '&' of statement 'export type T1 = object & ComponentOptions<T1, T2>' in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I new new to typescript, I'm try to reading source code of Vue, but confused the grammar, what means '&' in following code, and any guys can tell me how find it the official documentation?

```js
/**
 * This type should be used when an array of strings is used for a component's `props` value.
 */
export type ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps<V extends Vue, Data, Methods, Computed, PropNames extends string> =
  object &
  ComponentOptions<V, DataDef<Data, Record<PropNames, any>, V>, Methods, Computed, PropNames[], Record<PropNames, any>> &
  ThisType<CombinedVueInstance<V, Data, Methods, Computed, Readonly<Record<PropNames, any>>>>;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: understanding union and Intersection types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61370779/typescript-understanding-union-and-intersection-types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '&' is an operator used for creating Intersection Types.

A intersection type is a type that contains attributes belonging to both types in the intersection.

```js
type A = {
  foo: string,
  bar: number,
}

type B = {
  baz: boolean,
  foo: string,
}

type C = A & B;
// type C = { foo: string, bar: number, baz: boolean }
```

You can read more about it here:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types

and here:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases

I hope I have helped!

Comment: my bad, I described union types. but I fixed now. thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

It's an intersection type, it allows combining multiple types into one.

For example:

```
interface A {
    a: string;
}

interface B {
    b: boolean;
}

type C = A & B;

const value: C = {
    a: 'a',
    b: true
};
```

Type C is a combination of the properties in A and B.

Check official documentation for additional reference:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types